# Manipulating inline style with angular does not work in IE

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-ng-repeat, inline-styles

I wanted to set the position of a div based on the return value of a function in an angular controller

The following works fine in FireFox and in chrome but in Internet explorer `{{position($index)}}%` is interpreted as a literal string value and therefore has no effect

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" style="left:{{position($index)}}%"></div>
```

Here is an example of the issue:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.items=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    $scope.position=function(i){
        var percent =[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70];
        return percent[i+1];
    }
});
```

And here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mx4w6uxz/)** to demonstrate

Does anyone have suggestions on how to rectify?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You must use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead of style, otherwise some browsers like `IE` will remove invalid style attribute values (presence of `{{}}` etc makes it invalid) before even angular has a chance to render it. When you use `ng-style` angular will calculate the expression and add the inline style attributes to it.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-style="{left: position($index) + '%'}"></div>
```

Since you are anyways calculating the position you could as well add `%` from the `position` and send it. Also remember that calling a function in ng-repeat will invoke the function every digest cycle, so you may want to be careful not to do too much intensive operations inside the method.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-style="{left: position($index)}">{{item}}</div>
```

and return

```
  return percent[i+1] + "%";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ct7y2dv4/)

Answer (score 31):

If you want to use angular binding expression `{{}}` just like normal style attribute like `style="width:{{someScopeVar}}"`,
use **`ng-attr-style`** and it will work perfectly IE (and obviously other smarter ones) :)

check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0s4twkhv/2/) ... Checked with Angular JS 1.4.8

here I have shown the usage of `style`, `ng-style` and `ng-attr-style`

**THE HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controller">

        <div style="background:{{bgColor}}">
            This will NOT get colored in IE
        </div>

        <div ng-attr-style="background:{{bgColor}}">
            But this WILL get colored in IE
        </div>

        <div ng-style="styleObject">
            And so is this... as this uses a json object and gives that to ng-style
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**THE JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.bgColor = "yellow";        
    $scope.styleObject = {"background": "yellow"};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ng-style` will work to resolve this problem. You can use conditionally style using `ternary operator`.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-style="{'display':showInfo?'block':'none'}">
</div>
```