# Converting a style into ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

My AngularJS app doesn't work on IE11. I learnt I need to convert every inline `style` which contains angular variables into `ng-style` tags

This is what I've got:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="color: {{ ::channel.colour }};"></div>
```

how to convert it into an `ng-style`?

I tried converting it like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" ng-style="color: {{ ::channel.colour }};"></div>
```

but it doesn't work

**EDIT**

General issue:
[Manipulating inline style with angular does not work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655434/manipulating-inline-style-with-angular-does-not-work-in-ie)

Comment: I dont feel you need to convert to ng-style. we have developed an app which runs well in IE11. try using ng-class and put the css in that class in a seperate css file.

Comment: have a look at my edit

Comment: post your controller logic where you are setting channel.colour. I hope you just have to remove ::. Instead {{ ::channel.colour}} try {{ channel.colour}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be scope variable is not binding to style or ng-style.
you need to try something like

```
<div id="mydiv" ng-style="colour"></div>
```

And in controller

```
$scope.colour= {
  "color": "red"
}
```